# Ruby: Ignore last line of a file and add a row to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have the following:

```
twodarray = []
File.open("SG_hum50_LODG.gro", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    textarray = line.split()
    textarray[0],textarray[1],textarray[2] = textarray[1],textarray[0],textarray[2].to_i
    textarray[1] = textarray[1].gsub(/:/, '').to_i
    twodarray << textarray
  end
end
```

Which works pretty well. The problem I am having is I need to ignore the last line of the text file, and I need to add

```
["Sensor", "Timestamp", "Sensor Value"],
```

As the first row in the array.

Comment: You don't want to aggregate every line of a file unless you are _absolutely_ sure the file will fit into memory. Instead, read a line, process it, and, if you're creating a new file, immediately write it. You can end up consuming all memory otherwise. _Why_ are you aggregating to `twodarray`? Your question sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968). Once we know why you are taking this path we can suggest usable solutions, but as is all the answers continue that potential problem and don't sidestep it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
twodarray = [["Sensor", "Timestamp", "Sensor Value"]]
File.open("SG_hum50_LODG.gro", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    textarray = line.split()
    textarray[0], textarray[1], textarray[2] =textarray[1], textarray[0], textarray[2].to_i
    textarray[1].gsub!(/:/, '').to_i
    twodarray << textarray
  end
end
twodarray.pop
```

Comment: This worked famously. Thank you so much. In the output, however, column 1 has qoutes around it...I'm not sure why, is there a way to remove those? Column 1 is supposed to be integers.

Comment: Yeah instead of `textarray[0], textarray[1], textarray[2] =textarray[1], textarray[0], textarray[2].to_i` do `textarray[0], textarray[1], textarray[2] =textarray[1].to_i, textarray[0], textarray[2].to_i`

Comment: If I could bother for one more question, how would I go about making the output of this a one dimensional array? I just need to remove the outer [] surround the whole thing.

Comment: Sure. Call `twodarray.flatten!` at the end. This flattens the array in place.

Comment: That has me almost there...using flatten! like that removes the outer brackets and the inner brackets. What I am trying to get is ["TEXT", 1, 1], ["TEXT", 2, 2],...etc but with no outer brackets

Comment: What you're asking for is not a structure in ruby. You can't have objects separated by commas but not in an array. In ruby `a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` is just syntactical sugar for `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Note that if packaged in a method, `twodarray` needs to be added as the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
twodarray << textarray unless line[f.last]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def read_sensor_data(fname, first_arr)
  File.open(fname, "r") do |f|
    f.each_line.with_object([first_arr]) do |line, arr|
      next if f.eof?
      sensor, time, value, *rest = line.split
      arr << [time.delete(':').to_i, sensor, value.to_i, *rest]
    end
  end
end
```

`*rest` is not needed if every line of the file contains no more than three words.

**Example**

```
FName = "demo"
```

Create a file.

```
File.write FName,
<<-_
heat  10:21 16
sound 11:45 74
That's all, folks!
_
  #=> 49
```

Check the file.

```
puts File.read FName
heat  10:21 16
sound 11:45 74
That's all, folks!
```

Try the method.

```
read_sensor_data FName, ["Sensor", "Timestamp", "Sensor Value"]
  #=> [["Sensor", "Timestamp", "Sensor Value"],
  #    [1021, "heat", 16],
  #    [1145, "sound", 74]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful aggregating lines in a file into an array because that's not a scalable solution. Only do it if you can guarantee that the file being loaded, plus the needs of your script, will never grow beyond the available free memory.

Your question isn't clear about what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to modify a file on disk, which is easily done using `File.foreach` to read the incoming file line-by-line.

There's a couple ways to ignore the last line, but the easiest is to count the lines in the file then read all but the last line. There are many ways to count the lines in a file, the easiest is to use the *nix `wc -l` command, which is designed to do it:

```
lines_in_file = `wc -l /path/to/file`.to_i
```

and for a pure Ruby solution I'd do something like this:

```
lines_in_file = File.foreach('input.txt').inject(0){ |i, _| i + 1 }
```

Then it's a simple matter of counting `lines_in_file - 1` lines. This is untested but it looks about right:

```
INPUT_FILE = 'input.txt' 

lines_in_file = File.foreach(INPUT_FILE).inject(0){ |i, _| i + 1 }

File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts '"Sensor", "Timestamp", "Sensor Value"'
  File.foreach(INPUT_FILE) do |li|
    fo.puts li
    break if $. == (lines_in_file - 1)
  end
end
```